# Are BSD/Posix sockets reentrant?

Tags: concurrency, posix, sockets

Can several threads operate on the same socket descriptor, i.e `accept(sock_fd)` at the same time without concern?

The platform I'm mostly interested in is POSIX/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are "reentrant" - kernel locks the socket structure while working on it (see [Linux accept source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/net/tipc/socket.c#L1499) for example), so only one thread would get the client connection.