# Can an application handle N accept connections and each accept uses an independent thread

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, posix

I have C linux TCP Client/Server application.
I came up with a strange scenario, but I don't know if there are any consequences with this application.
I have a server side that can accept N connections, for example this server will accept 100 connections. 
In this scenario I create the listen socket in the main thread, then I create 100 threads and each thread has an independent accept() and a select() iomux, also each thread can only accept one connection.

My concerns here, if two simultaneous accept() want to accept the same socket(connection) because of the select is a ready to read on the same socket, I don't know if the simultaneous accepts are thread safe in kernel and only one accept can handle that incoming connection and the other will wait for another connection?

I tried that on my RedHat machine that works fine, but I don't know If I am a lucky enough to avoid a deadlock!

Thanks

```
rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr_in *)& groupSock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    CHECK_VALUE("Bind address error", rc, 0, goto cleanup);

    rc = listen(sd, 10);
    CHECK_VALUE("listen", rc, 0, goto cleanup);

    for(; count< num_socks; count++){

            par_data[count].sd = sd;
            par_data[count].thread_num = count;
            par_data[count].err_chk = -1;

            rc = pthread_create(&thread_id[count], NULL, accept_sock_thread,  (void *)& par_data[count]);
            CHECK_VALUE("pthread_create", rc, 0, goto cleanup);


    }

void * accept_sock_thread(void* atr){

    int                     rc;
    int                     sock            = INVALID_SOCKET;
    int                     datalen         = config.traffic;
    char                    *databuf        = NULL;
    struct thread_data      *data           = NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in      tcp_remote;
    struct timeval          t;
    socklen_t               size;
    fd_set                  socks;

    databuf = malloc(sizeof(char) * datalen);
    memset(databuf, 0, datalen);

    data = (struct thread_data*) atr;
    DEBUG(my_debug_flags, ENTER_FUNCT, ("Enter Function accept_sock_thread thread_num %d \n", data->thread_num));


    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    FD_SET(data->sd, &socks);
    t.tv_sec = 25;
    t.tv_usec = 0;
    rc = select(data->sd + 1 , &socks, NULL, NULL,&t);
    if(rc < 0){
            VL_MISC_ERR(("Error in select with Errno: %d", errno));
            goto cleanup;
    }
    else if(rc == 0){
            VL_MISC_ERR(("Accept Select returned a TIEMOUT."));
            goto cleanup;
    }


    size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sock = accept(data->sd, (struct sockaddr *)& tcp_remote, &size);
    CHECK_NOT_EQUAL("tcp accept error", sock, INVALID_SOCKET,  goto cleanup);
cleanup:
    //      sleep(2); /* avoid EOF */
    if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET){

            rc = close(sock);
            if(rc != 0){
                    data->err_chk = -1;
            }
    }
           return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code handling the connection? The scenario you describe can be good but it also depends on the implementation

Comment: sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr_in *)& groupSock, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
rc = listen(sd, 100);
for(; count< num_socks; count++){
par_data[count].sd = sd;
par_data[count].thread_num = count;
par_data[count].err_chk = -1;
rc = pthread_create(&thread_id[count], NULL, accept_sock_thread,  (void *)& par_data[count]);
}

Comment: Actually got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accept()` is thread-safe and reentrant according to POSIX.

This means that two call of accept on the same descriptor should not give an undefined behaviour. One of the accept will open the socket and the other will return an error.

You can see a little more there :

[Is accept() thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124320/is-accept-thread-safe)
[Are BSD/Posix sockets reentrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133224/are-bsd-posix-sockets-reentrant)

Comment: Also see this for Apache using a mutex to ensure only one process handles the accept().  Not sure if this applies to threads as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048701/why-does-apache-mpm-prefork-c-use-a-mutex-to-protect-accept?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Only one thread is going to `accept` the connection.  The kernel insures this.  It has been this way in the unix/posix world for a very long time now.

Comment: The kernel *ensures* this. Unless the kernel promises to compensate any process for which it's not true?

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread would `accept()`, so far so good ... - but before this **all** threads will be triggered to have `select()` return, which might not be what you want.

So if you'd had N threads sleeping in `select()` and **one** connection comes in **all** threads would wake up, but only **one** would be needed, as only **one** would succeed in `accept()`ing.

Comment: yes all selects will return ready to read and then the lucky accept will get the connection... Thank you

Comment: @GEEKS: From the performance perspective I'd consider this quiet inefficient. Also see this answer to the question linked by *Richard Chambers* in his comment above.

Answer (score 0):

To use `accept()` on same socket object from multiple threads/processes is not only standard, but also widly used strategy. From my knowledge **apache** does this. **nginx** does this too but in slightly different fashion.

Do note: `select()` can wake up multiple threads, but only one of them will accept connection, while others will either **a)** hang in `accept()` or **b)** return -1 and set `errno` to **EAGAIN** in case of non-blocking IO. Since you are using `select()` before accept() I suppose socket descriptor **is** in non blocking mode. So this can lead to some threads never serve a connection.

Also I would advise you to never close same socket in multiple threads. This can lead to very nasty and hard to debug consequences. Either use wrapper and `shared_ptr` or assign to one of threads a role of 'owner of socket'.